# Rename tag jpa to jakarta-persistence

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

The tag [jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa) stands for "Java Persistence API", which is/was a part of Java EE.

As Java EE is now [maintained by the Eclipse Foundation](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee), Java EE has been renamed to Jakarta EE.

With that, Java Persistence API was also renamed to "Jakarta Persistence".

Because of that, I suggest renaming the tag [jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa) to [jakarta-persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-persistence) as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag) and create a tag synonym from [jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa) to [jakarta-persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-persistence) if required.

The transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE is described [in this oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee) and the documentation of Jakarta persistence can be found [here](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/).

I think that the tag info/wiki should be updated according to this too and a note that it is the same should be added.

For example, the tag info could be changed from

> The Java Persistence API (JPA) is a Java specification for accessing, persisting, and managing data between Java objects/classes and a relational database. It is part of the EJB 3.0 specification and is the industry standard approach for Object to Relational Mapping (ORM).

to

> Jakarta Persistence (previously Java Persistence API/JPA) is a Java specification for accessing, persisting, and managing data between Java objects/classes and a relational database. It is part of the EJB 3.1 specification and is the industry standard approach for Object to Relational Mapping (ORM).

Comment: I do a lot with JPA and this is the first I'm hearing of this. To me Jakarta is a city, and the old Apache project umbrella for stuff like ant and tomcat. That being said a lot of people do JPA without the overhead of JavaEE, eg thru the use of libraries and frameworks like Spring.

Comment: Oracle gave Java EE to the eclipse foundation. Because of legal reasons, they had to rename it to Jakarta EE. (Oracle has the rights on the name `Java`). Jakarta EE was released a bit less than a year and Jakarta EE 9 will be released in summer this year.

Comment: And JPA is renamed because it is a part of Java EE.

Comment: Implemented this as proposed in the answer, instead of renaming the tag.

Comment: All the previous versions were called Java Persistence API though, so every question now tagged `jpa` would then be wrong if it were renamed.

Comment: @OrangeDog Jakarta Persistence is basically a new version of the Java Persistence API as the project has been moved to the Eclipse Foundation - it's the same thing just newer. with someone else maintaining it and with a different root package name because of legal reasons.

Comment: @dan1st yes, that's my point.

Comment: @OrangeDog So why would renaming it making the tagging wrong if they are about the same thing?

Comment: @dan1st because the rename is not retroactive. Only the current version is called Jakarta Persistence API, All the previous versions are called Java Persistence API. Fortunately, all versions are called JPA, so just leave it alone.

Comment: Nevermind. I thought it was about something else. This was decided/declined that way already (see the answer).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JPA is an acronym, and thankfully because Jakarta Persistence API also fits with the pattern, it'd be a huge shift to a lot of people supporting older JPA applications to suddenly have to refer to it by a new acronym.

So how about this instead?

- Update the tag info with the appropriate verbiage (replacing Java with Jakarta)
- Create a new tag synonym of [jakarta-persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-persistence) and have it link to [jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa)
- Keep the *existing* [jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa) tag since the questions in it would *still* be relevant (from what I can tell)
- If new versions of Jakarta Persistence API offer significant departures from the older JPA versions, allow for a [jakarta-persistence-version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-persistence-version) tag to be leveraged (similar to Python 2 and Python 3, or AngularJS and Angular)