# Synonymize [javax.persistence] to [jpa]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tags [javax.persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javax.persistence) and [jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa) are about the same thing - The Java Persistence API.
Both tags have tag wikis and excerpt but the [tag wiki of [javax.persistence]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javax.persistence/info) only contains a Wikipedia link.

Since [it is maintained by the Eclipse Foundation](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee), it has been renamed to Jakarta EE (as well as the root package which has been renamed from `javax.persistence` to `jakarta.persistence`). Recently, a similar tag, [jakarta.persistence-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta.persistence-api) has been created.

I propose to synonymize both [javax.persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javax.persistence) and [jakarta.persistence-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta.persistence-api) to [jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa) as people might be looking for tags starting with `javax.persistence` or `jakarta.persistence`.

Note that both [jakarta-persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-persistence) and [java-persistence-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-persistence-api) are already synonyms of [jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa).

Comment: Related: [Rename tag jpa to jakarta-persistence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394611)

Comment: This is now completed; [tag:jpa] now has [four synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jpa/synonyms).