# Rename [jsf] to [jakarta-faces]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Since version 4, Java Server Faces (or Jakarta Server Faces) has been renamed to Jakarta Faces (or simply Faces). I think the same should be done with the [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf) tag (rename it to [jakarta-faces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-faces)). We could keep the old name as a synonym. Version specific tags (like [jsf-1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf-1.2)) should remain intact.

See also:

- https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2021/11/whats-new-in-faces-40.html
- https://github.com/jakartaee/faces/issues/1552
- [Rename [java-ee] to [jakarta-ee]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364137/rename-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee)
- [Version tags reloaded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267996/version-tags-reloaded)

Comment: +1 but I feel like if we go this path, all other JEE artifacts should be renamed along for consistency.

Comment: I would opt to rename `java-ee-*` to `jakarta-ee-*` and leave `jee-*` names untouched (but change the description and wiki).

Comment: I think for tagging purposes it should be `jakarta-faces` as mentioned `faces` is too generic here on stack overflow for a tag.  In general though everywhere else outside of SO it should be just `Faces`

Comment: Related: [Rename java-ee to jakarta-ee](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364137/525036), [Tag rename + alias request: javamail -> jakarta-mail](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401751/525036), [Rename tag jpa to jakarta-persistence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394611/525036)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to keep the [jsf-*] version tags intact? Don't they would struggle from the same ambiguity as jsf tag does?

Comment: Well there are only tags with versions below 4, so from the era the technology was still called Java Server Faces. Technically there is no such thing as Jakarta Faces 1.2. With 2.3 it's a bit of a different story. I think there was a topic on completely removing those version tags. Which is also an option.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267996/version-tags-reloaded

Comment: There is also a number of somewhat well-known coding standards for C++ called "Joint Strike Fighter" = JSF. An avionics-developed safer subset of C++. Though none of the [questions about it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=joint+strike+fighter) seem to use the JSF tag.

Comment: @Lundin Because they are removed by the community. For example https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11195163/revisions

Comment: @JasperdeVries Oh okay. Well that calls for a disambiguation of the tag then.

Comment: Is there any chance the tag will be renamed? @BalusC already gave a +1 (he is the top JSF user on SO). Do we need additional approvals?

Answer (score 5):

Please, go ahead migrating [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf) to [jakarta-faces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-faces).

Like as with [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee) -> [jakarta-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee), the old tag should definitely become a synonym.

Other suggestions in order to be consistent under the [Jakarta EE umbrella](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/):

- [servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servlets) -> [jakarta-servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-servlet) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/
- [jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsp) -> [jakarta-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-pages) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/pages/
- [jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jstl) -> [jakarta-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-tags) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/
- [el](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/el) -> [jakarta-expression-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-expression-language) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/
- [jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa) -> [jakarta-persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-persistence) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/
- [cdi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdi) -> [jakarta-cdi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-cdi) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/
- [ejb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ejb) -> [jakarta-enterprise-beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-enterprise-beans) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/enterprise-beans/
- [bean-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bean-validation) -> [jakarta-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-validation) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/
- [jsonb-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonb-api) -> [jakarta-jsonb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-jsonb) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/jsonb/
- [jakarta-ee-security-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee-security-api) -> [jakarta-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-security) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/security/
- [jakarta-websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-websockets)+[java-websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-websocket) -> [jakarta-websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-websocket) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/websocket/
- [jax-rs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jax-rs) -> [jakarta-restful-ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-restful-ws) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/
- [jax-ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jax-ws) -> [jakarta-xml-ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-xml-ws) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-web-services/
- [jms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jms) -> [jakarta-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-messaging) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/messaging/

For reference, the following tags exist already, just keep them as-is:

- [jakarta-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-ee) https://jakarta.ee/
- [jakarta-jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-jsonp) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/jsonp/
- [jakarta-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-mail) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/
- [jakarta-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-mvc) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mvc/
- [jakarta-annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jakarta-annotations) https://jakarta.ee/specifications/annotations/

As to version tags, my personal recommendation is to ban/synonymize them. [They are absolutely not helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267996/version-tags-reloaded).